# org_scalajs_dom_raw_HTMLDocument(...).createRange is not a function

Tags: scala.js, scalatags

I'm upgrading scalatags from 0.6.7 to 0.9.3 as part of upgrading scalaJS from 0.6.x to 1.4.0.

I got the following error in some of my tests:

```
scala.scalajs.js.JavaScriptException: TypeError: $m_Lorg_scalajs_dom_package$(...).document__Lorg_scalajs_dom_raw_HTMLDocument(...).createRange is not a function
```

Tracing the code, I believe it occurs while executing line 141 of the following scalatags code in `scalatags.JsDom:

[image: offending scalatags code]

I extracted just the `createRange` call into a separate test and got the same error.  "creating range" was printed; "created range" was not and it produced the same exception as above.

[image: isolated test]

`createRange()` is a native function.

Googling "createRange is not a function" yields a number of similar issues, all seem to be related to testing (but not with ScalaJS).  Many of them indicate the "fix" is to monkey-patch `document` with your own version of `createRange`.  Really?

I initially thought this was an issue with scalatags.  Then I thought it's with the scalajs library.  Now I'm thinking it's something with Node.js, although Google is not producing any smoking guns.

Suggestions on how to proceed?  Try to monkey patch `document`?

Comment: What environment are you using for testing? Is it `jsdom`? Perhaps `jsdom` is missing `createRange`, and that's why you (and others in other languages) get issues in tests with that function. I would say try to monkey patch `document`, as suggested elsewhere.

Comment: Yes, using `jsdom`.  Will try a monkey patch tomorrow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Summary:  jsdom appears to be missing the `document.createRange` function when using Node.js for testing.  Others in other languages have [similar problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61691375/jest-test-typeerror-document-createrange-is-not-a-function).

The following monkey patch worked for me.  After developing this, I noticed that [Facade Types](http://www.scala-js.org/doc/interoperability/facade-types.html) has a section on monkey typing.

Also, the library code that tickled this bug (scalatags) actually calls `document.createRange().createContextualFragment(v)`.  So I needed to provide something for that as well.

```scala
  import scala.scalajs.js
  import org.scalajs.dom.document
  js.Dynamic.global.document.createRange = () ⇒
    js.Dynamic.literal(
      setStart = () => js.Dynamic.literal(),
      setEnd   = () => js.Dynamic.literal(),
      commonAncestorContainer = js.Dynamic.literal(
        nodeName      = "BODY",
        ownerDocument = document
      ),
      createContextualFragment = (v: String) ⇒ {
        val p = document.createElement("p")
        p.appendChild(document.createTextNode(v))
      }
    )
```